# How to iterate through an Array List and remove a user?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to iterate through my ArrayList and find a a value that's equal to the condition I have set for it using a while loop. Once the program iterates through the users and finds the value that matches the condition, I am trying to get it to then remove that user from the list. Everything seems to be working fine but it doesn't seem to be removing anything from the Array List. Here is the code:

**Main class**

```
package main;

public class Main{
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("****************For loop****************");
       for (int counter=2; counter<=40; counter+=2) {
       System.out.println(counter);
    }
    System.out.println("****************While loop****************");

    int counter = 1;
    int increment = 2;
    int loopexeccounter = 0;
    while (counter <= 500) {
        loopexeccounter = loopexeccounter + 1;
        System.out.println(counter);
    counter = counter + increment++;
    }
System.out.print("This loop iteratted "+loopexeccounter+" times.\n");
     {

     //public User callUserGroup;   
UserGroup userGroupObject = new UserGroup();
userGroupObject.removeFirstUser();
userGroupObject.removeLastUser();
userGroupObject.removeUser();
System.out.println("***********Number of users Array List***********");
System.out.println(userGroupObject.userGroup.size());
System.out.println("***********User's details***********");
for (User curUser : userGroupObject.getUserGroup())
{
   System.out.println(curUser.toString()); 
} }
}
}
```

**UserGroup class (used to make array list and perform functions)**

```
package main;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class UserGroup {

ArrayList<User> userGroup = new ArrayList<>();
User userOne;
public UserGroup()
{
  addUser(new User("lnb1g16", "Student", "Lee"));
  addUser(new User("hpf1g17", "Staff", "Harry"));
  addUser(new User("jks1g25", "Student", "Jordon"));
  addUser(new User("ohw1237", "Staff", "Oliver"));
  addUser(new User("ahs1213", "Student", "Jordon"));
  addUser(new User("tqn1294", "Student", "Taylor"));
}

public void addUser(User inUser)
{
  //userGroup.add(new User("LeeB123", "Staff", "Lee"));
  userGroup.add(inUser);
}
public ArrayList<User> getUserGroup() {
    return userGroup;
}
public void removeFirstUser()  {
    userGroup.remove(0);

}
public void getArrayListSize()  {
    userGroup.size();
}
public void removeLastUser()  {
    userGroup.remove(4);
}
public void removeUser()  {
    Iterator<User> it = userGroup.iterator();    
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        User xxx = it.next();

        if (xxx.equals("jks1g26")) {

            it.remove();
        }
    }

}
}
```

**User class (defines user's details)**

```
package main;

class User {

  String username;
  String userType;
  String name;


    User(String username, String userType, String name) {

    this.username = username;
    this.userType = userType;
    this.name = name;
    }

  public String getUsername() {
      return username;
  }

  public String getUserType() {
      return userType;
  }

   public String getName() {
      return name;
  }

  public String setUserType(String admin) {
      return userType = admin;
  }
  @Override
public String toString() {
    return username + " " + userType;
}
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You asked this exact question yesterday. Please don't ask it again. You even got an answer yesterday.

Comment: This is slightly different,I know how to remove a user but the part in which I'm stuck on is how to use the iterate method and find a value which is equal to what the condition is looking for as opposed to just removing any user from the Array List. Sorry if you thought it was too similar though but there are some differences.

Comment: This was incorrectly and prematurely closed. If you read properly, the code is different, and there's a different problem here. Please reopen.

Comment: Anyway. The answer is to replace `xxx.equals("jks1g26")` with `xxx.getUsername().equals("jks1g25")`. That is: 1. a `User` should not be equal to a `String`, so you probably meant to compare the username string; 2. you mistyped the username.

Comment: Ah okay thanks very much for your help!